# Exception while trying to execute axis2 service client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I am using Axis2 Wsdl2java from SOAP based service which is hosted on IIS. I have set requestHeader first and then tried to execute Create method in client that accepts two parameters payload xml as OMElement and requesType as string but getting exception as below.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was  unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlNode[]' to type 'System.String'.
```

can someone please help me to understand the problem with code below or why I am getting above exception?

Please see below my client code:

```
 package net.approva.BizRights.Services;

 public class Client{
    public static void main(java.lang.String args[]){
    try
    {
       ApprovalRequestManagerStub stub =
       new ApprovalRequestManagerStub("serverurl.asmx");            
       Create(stub);     
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
       System.out.println("\n\n\n");
    }
    }
    /* Create */
    public static void Create(ApprovalRequestManagerStub stub){
        try
        {            
            net.approva.BizRights.Services.ApprovalRequestManagerStub.Create req = new Create();            

            java.lang.String content = "<approvalrequests xmlns=\"http://www.approva.net/ApprovalRequest.xsd\"><approvalrequest><name>USER  002371(ABC)</name><type>OnlyWhatIfAnalysis</type><status>SubmittedForWhatIf</status><priority>Medium</priority><applicationid>2</applicationid><applicationname>SAP AI Connection</applicationname><format>NoConstraints</format><requestdetails><roleassignment><users><user><id>591</id><userid>ABC</userid><lastname>002371</lastname><firstname>USER</firstname><validfromdate>1900-01-01</validfromdate><validtodate>1900-01-01</validtodate></user></users><roles><role revoke=\"false\"><id>3172</id><name>SAP_ICM_S_CUST</name><fromdate>1900-01-02T00:00:00</fromdate><todate>1900-01-01T00:00:00</todate><roletype>4</roletype><description>Commissions: Customizing</description></role></roles></roleassignment><applicationscope><scope displaytext=\"Application\" name=\"firstlevelscope\"><scopevalue displaytext=\"SAP AI Connection\">SAP AI Connection</scopevalue></scope></applicationscope><comment /><asanotheruser /><requestor><id>1</id><userid>administrator</userid></requestor><whatifliveverify>1</whatifliveverify><analysisresults /></requestdetails><requestor><lastname /><firstname /><displayname>administrator</displayname></requestor><applicationscope><scope name=\"firstlevelscope\"><scopevalue>SAP AI Connection</scopevalue></scope></applicationscope><liveverify>1</liveverify></approvalrequest></approvalrequests>";

                                                org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory fac = org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
                                                org.apache.axiom.om.OMNamespace omNs = fac.createOMNamespace("http://www.approva.net/BizRights/Services", null);                                              
                                                org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement _valueObjXML = fac.createOMElement("approvalrequests", omNs);                                                
                                                _valueObjXML.addChild(fac.createOMText(_valueObjXML, content));                          

                                                req.setObjXML(_valueObjXML);                                       

                                                System.out.println(_valueObjXML.getText());                                              

            req.setObjType(WellKnownType.ApprovalRequest);

            BRSoapHeader brSOAP =  new BRSoapHeader();
            brSOAP.setProfileID(1);
            brSOAP.setCallingModuleName(null);
            brSOAP.setOpDocumentationXML(null); 

            BRSoapHeaderE brSoapHeader = new BRSoapHeaderE();
            brSoapHeader.setBRSoapHeader(brSOAP);       

            net.approva.BizRights.Services.ApprovalRequestManagerStub.CreateResponse res = new CreateResponse();
            res = stub.create(req, brSoapHeader);         

            System.out.println(res.toString());
            System.out.println("Request Creation done using Axis2");
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\n\n\n");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have already included approvalrequests tag at this line in content string declaration ,

```
java.lang.String content = "<approvalrequests xmlns=\"http://www.approva.net/ApprovalRequest.xsd\"><approvalrequest><name>USER  002371(ABC)</name><type>OnlyWhatIfAnalysis</type><status>SubmittedForWhatIf</status><priority>Medium</priority><applicationid>2</applicationid><applicationname>SAP AI Connection</applicationname><format>NoConstraints</format><requestdetails><roleassignment><users><user><id>591</id><userid>ABC</userid><lastname>002371</lastname><firstname>USER</firstname><validfromdate>1900-01-01</validfromdate><validtodate>1900-01-01</validtodate></user></users><roles><role revoke=\"false\"><id>3172</id><name>SAP_ICM_S_CUST</name><fromdate>1900-01-02T00:00:00</fromdate><todate>1900-01-01T00:00:00</todate><roletype>4</roletype><description>Commissions: Customizing</description></role></roles></roleassignment><applicationscope><scope displaytext=\"Application\" name=\"firstlevelscope\"><scopevalue displaytext=\"SAP AI Connection\">SAP AI Connection</scopevalue></scope></applicationscope><comment /><asanotheruser /><requestor><id>1</id><userid>administrator</userid></requestor><whatifliveverify>1</whatifliveverify><analysisresults /></requestdetails><requestor><lastname /><firstname /><displayname>administrator</displayname></requestor><applicationscope><scope name=\"firstlevelscope\"><scopevalue>SAP AI Connection</scopevalue></scope></applicationscope><liveverify>1</liveverify></approvalrequest></approvalrequests>";
```

Then again you are adding another approvalrequests tag here,

```
org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement _valueObjXML = fac.createOMElement("approvalrequests", omNs);
```

Comment: I will try removing it using another overload of createOMElement but do you think this exception is due to this line of code? while debugging I found it sends "content" XML  only and not the appended one. I have tried running code without line below and got the same exception..... System.out.println(_valueObjXML.getText());

Comment: I have observed that this is happening because OMElement get serialized as a XML instead of string, If someone can help to understand serealization process of OMElement in AXIS2 can help me ..